# Override rails 4 delete_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have written a concern to include into data models that will manage our auditable fields in our tables. This successfully overrides `delete`, `destroy` & `update`, but I am not able to catch the `delete_all` that executes an undesirable `DELETE * FROM ....`

```
module Concerns
  module Auditable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def auth_id
      Authentication.current ? Authentication.current.id : nil
    end

    def deletion_attributes
      { deleted_at: Time.now.utc, deleted_by: auth_id,
        modified_at: Time.now.utc, modified_by: auth_id }
    end

    def touch
      self.created_at ||= Time.now.utc
      self.created_by ||= auth_id
      self.modified_at = Time.now.utc
      self.modified_by = auth_id
    end

    def deleted?
      deleted_at.present?
    end

    def delete
      destroy
    end

    def destroy
      # destroy_associates (still to implement)
      update_attributes(deletion_attributes)
    end

    def undelete
      update_attributes(deleted_at: nil, deleted_by: nil,
                        modified_at: Time.now.utc, modified_by: auth_id)
    end

    def delete_all
      puts "this is never reached"
    end

    # Set ActiveRecord::Base of caller
    def self.included(base)
      unless base.ancestors.include?(ActiveRecord::Base)
        fail "You can only include this if #{base} extends ActiveRecord::Base"
      end
      base.class_eval do
        default_scope { where("#{table_name}.deleted_at IS NULL") }
        before_save :touch

        def self.show_deleted
          unscoped.where("#{table_name}.deleted_at IS NOT NULL")
        end

        def delete_all
          puts "this is also never reached"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is not the right way to override the class methods.

```
def self.included(base)
  unless base.ancestors.include?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    fail "You can only include this if #{base} extends ActiveRecord::Base"
  end
  base.class_eval do
    default_scope { where("#{table_name}.deleted_at IS NULL") }
    before_save :touch

    def self.show_deleted
      unscoped.where("#{table_name}.deleted_at IS NOT NULL")
    end

    def delete_all
      puts "this is also never reached"
    end
  end
end
```

---

**It works for me this way**

```
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def delete_all
      # do nothing
    end
  end
```

and make sure to `prepend Concerns::Auditable` to override the class methods.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  prepend Concerns::Auditable
end
```

You can also use the gem [ActsAsParanoid](https://github.com/ActsAsParanoid/acts_as_paranoid). It does the job for you!

Comment: Now when i add a where clause to the call it does not catch the delete_all
`Tag.where("id IS NOT NULL").delete_all`
`SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM tags WHERE...`

Comment: Because when you add a where clause you have a `ActiveRecord::Relation` type and you did not override the `delete_all` method for it.

Comment: how could I can override the delete_all method for ActiveRecord::Relation that only affect to one model?

Answer (score 1):

What about `destroy_all`? Callbacks are not called when using `delete_all` from the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/delete_all) it states "Deletes the records matching conditions without instantiating the records first, and hence not calling the destroy method nor invoking callbacks. This is a single SQL DELETE statement that goes straight to the database, much more efficient than destroy_all."